# unable to find C_kmns object when passed to .Fortran()

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to modify the `stats::kmeans` function to return the number of iterations ([see here](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e17/help/12/01/1049.html)). When I copy the source to my own file, modify the function and run it, I get an error about object `C_kmns` missing when trying to execute the `do_one` function. This object is passed to a `.Fortran` call and is not being created anywhere in the `kmeans` function. Where does this object come from?

The error I'm getting is

```
Error in do_one(nmeth) : object 'C_kmns' not found
```

Here's a code snippet of the "offending" call.

```
   do_one <- function(nmeth) {
      Z <-
               switch(nmeth,
                        { # 1
                           Z <- .Fortran(C_kmns, as.double(x), as.integer(m),
                                    as.integer(ncol(x)),
                                    ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C_kmns is a non-exported object in the stats namespace. You can solve the issue by telling R where to find it with stats:::C_kmns. in your example:

```
Z <- .Fortran(stats:::C_kmns, as.double(x), as.integer(m),
                                    as.integer(ncol(x)),
                                    ...
```

In general, when you get an object not found error, you can go looking for it with `getAnywhere("C_kmns")`